# How to add a negation to \p{S}

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

Hi someone offered me a great solution that included `\p{S}` to match any symbol in a regex. The problem is that I need to eliminate two symbols from the `\p{S}`. I don't want `&` or `'` to be a match.

I thought maybe `\p{S^&^'}` would work but it doesn't. I have looked online but I am not really sure what to search for.

Please help.

`\b\p{L}*[\p{S}\p{P}]((\p{L}[\p{P}\p{S}])|([\p{P}\p{S}]\p{L})|(\p{L}))+\b`

The other solution is `\b([a-zA-Z]+(?:[^\w\s^'&]|_)[a-zA-Z]*)|[a-zA-Z]*(?:[^\w\s^'&]|_)[a-zA-Z]+\b` but it catches words ending in punctuation. If it didn't do that it would work also.

Comment: Please specify *which* regular expression engine is being used. (If using .NET, for instance, consider `[\p{S}-[&']]`.)

Comment: Intriguing. According to [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), you can "match everything but a symbol" with `\P{S}` but there seems to be no standard way to exclude individual characters, other than expanding the whole Unicode range spanned by that block.

Comment: If you check the documentation for the [regex] tag you will see this note: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead `(?!.*[&'])`, i.e.

```
\b(?!.*[&'])\p{L}*[\p{S}\p{P}]((\p{L}[\p{P}\p{S}])|([\p{P}\p{S}]\p{L})|(\p{L}))+\b
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and words like `that's` are still caught. Am I asking for the wrong thing?

Comment: Updated, please try again - untested.

Comment: Test Code:

`public class test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String word2 = "hello, what's up? this won't work. 1.2.3 is f$$cked up. da*n";
  String word3 = "banana what's that g**k 3:00PM f..k";
 
  String regex = "\\b(?=[^&']*?\\b)\\p{L}*[\\p{S}\\p{P}]((\\p{L}[\\p{P}\\p{S}])|([\\p{P}\\p{S}]\\p{L})|(\\p{L}))+\\b";
  
  System.out.println(word2.replaceAll(regex, "flowers "));
  System.out.println(word3.replaceAll(regex, "flowers "));
  
 }
}`

Results are:

`hello, flowers  up? this flowers  work. 1.2.3 is flowers  up. flowers 
banana flowers  that flowers  3:00PM flowers 
`

Answer (score 1):

Use [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html) (if available):

```
[\p{S}-[&']]
```

If not available, use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!.?[&'])\p{S}
```

Comment: What is the usage of the `.?` in the lookahead form for?